# Large c2hs-inferred size of C enum

Tags: c, unix, haskell, ffi, c2hs

When writing the `Storable` instance of a C enum that has 5 options (using c2hs), the `{# sizeof #}` macro returns 4 (i.e. 4 bytes). Isn't this extremely wasteful, when 3 bits would suffice? Does this depend on the size of a memory word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of enum is implementation-defined. The standard says:

> **6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
> ...
>
> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined ...

BTW, in C++ one could specify the underlying type explicitly, e.g.:

```
enum E : int
{
    // ...
};
```